# Reload component when context changes? (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-context

So, I have this audio player that works fine and I'm able to use 'useContext' to grab whatever song the user clicks on. This returns an object and I just pass those parameters to the player. The issue I'm having is that the player doesn't reload/refresh when passed a new song/object. Any ideas how I can accomplish this? (Very new to React... apologies if it's something obvious) Thanks in advance!!

```
function Center() {

  const [state, dispatch] = useStoreContext();
  // console.log("STATE TEST", state)

  const audioListTest = [
    {
      name: state.currentAlbum.title,
      singer: state.currentAlbum.title,
      cover:
        state.currentAlbum.art,
      musicSrc: () => {
        return Promise.resolve(
          `${state.currentAlbum.songs[0]}`
        )
      },
    },
  ]

  const options = {
    audioLists: audioListTest
    (more options here omitted for brevity)
 }


  return (

    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#313131", height: "100vh" }}>
      <Search />
      <div id="centerDiv">
        <AlbumList />
      </div>
      <ReactJkMusicPlayer {...options} />
    </div>

  )
}

export default Center;
```

Comment: When and how are you passing the new song information. How does the player look like

Comment: Are you trying to pass audioListTest  as the props for ReactJkMusicPlayer?

Comment: @MosheSommers yes, audioListTest is an object that contains title, album, song url, etc